Increase uniform space between curve points before instancing
I'm building a train rail generator, and I'm hitting a wall on this particular issue.
Don't know much about geometry nodes yet, so bare with me :)
When generating the rails, I'd like to be able to control the spacing between each instanced board, uniformly, between all of the boards (witch changes based on the rail length), so basically expanding the space between them, leaving spaces at the end of the rail to connect different rail shapes.
How would I be able to achieve this with curve to points node? since it's the only way I am able to generate proper rotations and board directions for each instance? I was thinking about applying some kind of transformation to the points after the curve to points node, but I don't have enough knowledge on geo nodes and math for that I'm afraid.
Currently I also have exposed a density modifier for the amount of wood boards to create from the curve.



Hello ! Maybe change the mode of the Curve to Points node to Length ?

Use the Trim Curve node to add padding to the curve for the instances and the Curve to Points node set to Length mode:


Beautiful, exactly this. It was basically lack of knowledge on the existence of the "trim curve" node :)
